# Python concatenate_videoclips, strange audio and video glitches

Tags: python, concatenation, moviepy

I concatenated video clips with:

```
clip1=VideoFileClip('cutclip35.mp4')
clip2=VideoFileClip('cutclip165.mp4')
clip3=VideoFileClip('cutclip24.mp4')
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2,clip3],method='compose')
final_clip.write_videofile("my_concatenation.mp4",fps=20)
```

and get very weird glitches and I don't know what I did wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Here are the videos: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hbd4cwooy9xjf19/AACLcv4Rqtmj7YmGzbpmCTtsa?dl=0

using python 3.8.10

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same isue. Concatenating `.mp4` files directly causes glitches due to encoding issues.

The best way to avoid gltiches while concatenating is to convert the `.mp4` videos to `.ts` vidoes, concat the `.ts` videos and convert the final `.ts` video to `.mp4`

Using MoviePy to do all this process can be time consuming, hence, we can use `ffmpeg` directly to do all of it.

```py
def ConcatVideos(input_video_path_list:List[str], output_video_path:str, temporary_process_folder:str):    
    concat_file_list:List[str] = []
    for idx, input_video_path in enumerate(input_video_path_list, start=1):

        # convering individual file to .ts #
        temp_file_ts = f'{temporary_process_folder}/concat_{idx}.ts'
        os.system(f'''ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i {input_video_path} -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts {temp_file_ts} ''')
        concat_file_list.append(temp_file_ts)

    # concatenating .ts files and saving as .mp4 file #
    # ffmpeg will take care of encoding .ts to .mp4 #
    concat_string = '|'.join(concat_file_list)
    os.system(f'''ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i \
        "concat:{concat_string}" -c copy {output_video_path}''')
    
    return output_video_path

final_video_path = ConcatVideos(['input1.mp4','input2.mp4'], 'final_video.mp4', 'Temp')
# make sure '/Temp` folder exists or create it before-hand.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue. what i did is concatenate the audios and videos separately and combine them later.

```
video_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips,method='compose')
audioConc = concatenate_audioclips(audio_clips)
video_clip=video_clip.set_audio(audioConc)
video_clip.write_videofile("video-output.mp4",fps=24)
```